# With salt and cumin I am even tastier

Tags: riddle

> First throw my exterior away
>   Then grill my interior after
>   After that, eat and taste my exterior
>   In the end, throw my interior!

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Corn on the Cob!

First throw my exterior away

> the husks

Then grill my interior after

> the kernels

After that, eat and taste my exterior

> again the kernels, now on the outside

In the end, throw my interior!

> the cob

Personally, I recommend butter, salt, and black pepper